# Загружаю файл apk в google play console. Выдает - Название пакета com.example недопустимо

Tags: google-play-console

но изменить могу только одно слово, при выборе Refactor-Rename.

Comment: Через проводник поменял название папки exemple на zzz проект стал com.zzz.android.jastjava, нажал build - clean project и rebild, дальше создаю APK - создалось но при загрузке в play console выдает опять : Сбой при загрузке
Название пакета "com.example" недопустимо. Укажите другое.

Comment: вот это мне помогло https://stackoverflow.com/a/18637004/8389574

Answer (score 1):

В `GooglePlay` нельзя выгружать приложения с пакетами `com.example.*`. Создайте новый модуль с "нормальным" названием пакета и скопируйте туда свои классы.

Можно попробовать вручную переименовать все упоминания пакета в проекте: `Gradle`, `Manifest`, все классы. Но есть риск что-то упустить и тогда проект будет работать некорректно.